# Delete duplicate posts in WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I want to delete duplicate posts from my WordPress website
select duplicate posts work currectlly

```
 SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_type, a.post_status
    FROM wp_posts AS a
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
          FROM wp_posts
          WHERE post_type = 'post'
          AND post_status = 'publish'
          GROUP BY post_title
          HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
       ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
    AND b.min_id <> a.id
    AND a.post_type = 'post'
    AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

and

```
this query that i need has error
    DELETE a.*
    FROM wp_posts AS a
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
          FROM wp_posts
          WHERE post_type = 'post'
          AND post_status = 'publish'
          GROUP BY post_title
          HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
       ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
    AND b.min_id <> a.id
    AND a.post_type = 'post'
    AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

this is error message :

> Unexpected token (near a) Unexpected token (near .) Unexpected token
>   (near *)

Comment: Please tag proper RDBMS that you are using.....syntax may vary accordingly ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `SELECT` post IDs. Then Use `DELETE` statement with `WHERE IN` clause.

**NOTE:** Before executing whole query, test whether sub query in `IN()` clause returns correct ids.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM wp_posts AS a
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
          FROM wp_posts
          WHERE post_type = 'post'
          AND post_status = 'publish'
          GROUP BY post_title
          HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
       ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
    AND b.min_id <> a.id
    AND a.post_type = 'post'
    AND a.post_status = 'publish'
)
```

Comment: this error
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS p
WHERE p.ID IN (
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM wp_posts AS a
       INNER JOI' at line 1

Comment: @m.javadKoushki have pasted the code in single line? please try now

Comment: select ids dont get all duplicate posts.its wrong query

Comment: please check my topic again i add select duplicate posts query that work right

Comment: sorry this query work correctly I was not paying attention.thx